# How to select the second parameter when using Code completion in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

For example, when I type application, there are many options provided. The first parameter is always application, but the second parameter is quite different. The default selection is the first item: `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but what I want is another item: `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` , and its second parameter starts with 'h'. So how would I get this method quickly and strait forward (not by down arrow)?

[image]

Comment: Type and tab and type some more and tab. Asx you type more will be selected and there will be a dimmed portion, you will be able to see how much will be selected by a tab.

Comment: +1 for the correct use of the XCode tag!

Comment: Is that means i have to type `(UIApplication *)application` by myself, then type 'h' to get the second parameter by Code completion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will love this plugin:

https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin

[image]

[How to Install](https://github.com/FuzzyAutocomplete/FuzzyAutocompletePlugin#installation)

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>Control-N</kbd> <kbd>Return</kbd> to select the second one.

Also, I have caps-lock remapped to control in *System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Modifier Keys*, since that is where the control key was on the original UNIX era keyboards.

<kbd>Control-N</kbd> is also a UNIX era keyboard shortcut (equivalent to the down arrow). Most of the old keyboard shortcuts work in all well written mac apps.

Comment: He wants to quickly get to the sixth suggested completion, distinguished by the next segment of the selector being "h" instead of "d".